# Framework7: how to move HTML out as a separate file

Tags: html, ajax, html-framework-7

I have recently used Framework7 and it is great! However, as I've just started, I don't know how to move a part of page out to a separate HTML file. I have a very long index.html and and I'd like to move the inner pages into other HTML files. For example, in this case, I'd like to move the page index-3 inside of view-3 out and some how displays its content in the index.html.

I have looked up and down in the documentation but I can't find the solution there.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
<div id="view-3" class="view tab">
    <div class="pages">

      <!-- how to move this div out into another html file and loads its content, displays it here? -->

      <!-- from here -->

      <div data-page="index-3" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
          <div class="content-block-title">Another plain static view</div>
          <div class="content-block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel commodo massa, eu adipiscing mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus ultricies dictum neque, non varius tortor fermentum at. Curabitur auctor cursus imperdiet. Nam molestie nisi nec est lacinia volutpat in a purus. Maecenas consectetur condimentum viverra. Donec ultricies nec sem vel condimentum. Phasellus eu tincidunt enim, sit amet convallis orci. Vestibulum quis fringilla dolor.    </p>
            <p>Mauris commodo lacus at nisl lacinia, nec facilisis erat rhoncus. Sed eget pharetra nunc. Aenean vitae vehicula massa, sed sagittis ante. Quisque luctus nec velit dictum convallis. Nulla facilisi. Ut sed erat nisi. Donec non dolor massa. Mauris malesuada dolor velit, in suscipit leo consectetur vitae. Duis tempus ligula non eros pretium condimentum. Cras sed dolor odio.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel commodo massa, eu adipiscing mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus ultricies dictum neque, non varius tortor fermentum at. Curabitur auctor cursus imperdiet. Nam molestie nisi nec est lacinia volutpat in a purus. Maecenas consectetur condimentum viverra. Donec ultricies nec sem vel condimentum. Phasellus eu tincidunt enim, sit amet convallis orci. Vestibulum quis fringilla dolor.    </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- to here -->

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in some steps:

**1. Get the html from file**

```
var _html;

$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/template/name.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(html) {
        _html = html;
    }
});
```

**2. Compile with Template7 (You need `template7Pages: true` when init the app)**

```
var template = Template7.compile(_html);
```

**3. Add the html to your file**

```
$('#selector').html(template(data));
```

You can set data to this template. Read [Template7](http://www.idangero.us/template7/#.Vr35_vE3Fmo) for more information how to use this data inside of the template. I hope this help.